# Convertir Query con select dentro de Select

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

voy empezado el linq, como podria convertir este Query de Sql a Linq.
Gracias a todos de antemano.

Query

```
SELECT (SELECT 
         TOP 1                             t2.ccodigop 
  FROM   syncsalesuptest.dbo.datasalesupproduct AS t2 
  WHERE  t2.ccodigop = p.ccodigoproducto ) AS codigob, 
t1.codigoproducto                          AS codigoa, 
t1.descripcion                             AS nombre 
FROM     bbd1.dbo.productosa               AS t1 
         ( 
                select top 1 
                                           p2.ccodigop 
                FROM   bbd2.dbo.productosb AS t2 
                WHERE  t2.ccodigop = t1.codigoproducto ) IS NULL 
ORDER BY p.codigoproducto
```

RESULTADO

CodigoB,    CodigoA,    Nombre

NULL,   00100010,   Producto A

NULL,   20145009,   Producto B

NULL,   22138422,   Producto C

NULL,   22241719,   Producto D

TABLA 1

CODIGOPRODUCTO,     DESCRIPCION

00100010,   Producto A

20145009,   Producto B

22138422,   Producto C

22241719,   Producto D

TABLA 2

CODIGOPRODUCTO,     DESCRIPCION

20145009,   Producto B

22241719,   Producto D

Comment: No están mapeadas, las extraigo con Sql Command y los recibo como Inumerables las bases de datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tal vez no me di a explicar bien, ya lo solucione con una expresión lambda y enviando la información filtrada a una tercer lista y me funciono, si tienen alguna observación estoy al pendiente, Saludos.

```
                    var lstAdd =
                    (from f in 
                        (from a in lstSQLP
                        join b in resultado on a.Ccodigoproducto equals b.codigo
                        into c
                        from b in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new DataSalesupProduct
                        {
                            Ccodigop = a.Ccodigoproducto,
                            Cdescripcionp = a.Cnombreproducto,
                            Cstatus = a.Cstatusproducto,
                            Cidtask = (
                                        new Func<int>(
                                            () =>
                                            {
                                                if (b == null)
                                                    return 1;
                                                else
                                                    return 0;
                                            }
                                            )
                                        ).Invoke()
                        })
                    where f.Cidtask == 1 && f.Cstatus == 1
                    select new DataSalesupProduct 
                    {
                        Ccodigop = f.Ccodigop,
                        Cdescripcionp = f.Cdescripcionp,
                        Cstatus = f.Cstatus,
                        Cidtask = f.Cidtask
                    }
                    ).ToList();
```